# Django queryset update field increasing/descreasing its current value

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to change order of nodes in my tree. Everything works fine, but I would like to know if there is some beautiful, easy way of updating multiple fields by increasing its actual value by 1. Let me illustrate.

```
Objtree.objects.select_related().filter(pk__in = ids).update(sort_order = 1)
```

This code will change every sort_order column value to 1, but I would like to change it to something like:

```
Objtree.objects.select_related().filter(pk__in = ids).update(sort_order += 1)
# or
Objtree.objects.select_related().filter(pk__in = ids).update(self.sort_order = 1)
```

So... is there something like that? Nothing comes to my mind or my screen via googling.

Thanks for halp!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You want to use `F()` objects.

```
from django.db.models import F
Objtree.objects.filter(pk__in=ids).update(sort_order=F('sort_order')+1)
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)

Comment: Thanks! I need about Q objects, but totally forgot about F()